# Filling boolean [ ][ ] best way

Tags: java, boolean, discrete-mathematics

I'm using this instead of a BitSet for practice. I want to create different arrays and make my own methods for intersect, union, etc.
I also want to be able to print the array of booleans so I know what is happening. Thank you for your help.

Steps
1. Create private static method for filling a nxm boolean array with different values. 
2. Create new array and call method fillArray(myArray, int row, int col).
3. Print Array.

```
        boolean[][] myArray= new boolean[][];
        fillArray(myArray);



    }

    public static boolean[][] fillArray(boolean[][] bArray, int row, int col) {
        bArray = new boolean[row][col];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<row;i++) {
            bArray[i][0] = rand.nextBoolean();
            for(int j=0; j<col;j++) {
                bArray[j][0] = rand.nextBoolean();
            }
        }
        return bArray;
    }
```

}

Comment: You've told us what you want, you've almost asked a question, but you haven't quite - [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2970947)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give the Array a size for rows and columns. Try something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int row = 10;
    int col = 10;
    boolean[][] myArray= new boolean[row][col];
    fillArray(myArray, row, col);

    for(boolean[] row1: myArray){
        printRow(row1);
    }

}

public static boolean[][] fillArray(boolean[][] bArray, int row, int col) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    for(int i=0; i<row;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<col;j++) {
            bArray[i][j] = rand.nextBoolean();
        }
    }
    return bArray;
}

public static void printRow(boolean[] row) {
    for (boolean i : row) {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your `fill` method like this:

```
public static boolean[][] fillArray(int row, int col, Random rand) {
    boolean[][] bArray = new boolean[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            bArray[i][j] = rand.nextBoolean();
        }
    }
    return bArray;
}
```

Notes:

1. I've passed the `Random` instance as a parameter, because creating a new `Random` instance with a random seed is expensive.  (Hint: you need to get a random seed from the OS.
2. I have *removed* the `bArray` parameter because you were effectively ignoring it.
3. I have fixed the nested loop ... which was simply wrong.

Alternatively

```
public static boolean[][] fillArray(boolean[][] bArray, Random rand) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bArray[i].length; j++) {
            bArray[i][j] = rand.nextBoolean();
        }
    }
    return bArray;
}
```

This fills an entire array you have already created and provided.